# wordpress pagenavi направильная пагинация

Tags: wordpress

У меня на странице с постами стоит ограничение 2 поста (к примеру), а всего их 3, соответственно всего страниц должно быть 2, но их 6(в настройках pagenavi кол-во страниц для показа стоит 3), первые 2 поста на первой странице, 3-й пост на второй, а все остальные пустые, как ограничить количество страниц до действительного. Вот код цикла и пагинации:

```
 <?php 
      echo '<div class="news-block">';
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'news', 'paged' => $paged) );
        if ($query->have_posts() ) :
         while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
          $query->the_post();
          echo '<div class="news-column">';
          echo '<div class="news-img column">';
          echo '<div class="news-date">'. get_the_time('j M Y') . '</div>';
          echo '</div>' ;
          echo '<div class="news-content column">';
          echo '<div class="news-title">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
          echo  the_excerpt() . '</div>';
          echo '</div>';

         endwhile;

          echo '</div>';

          echo '<div class="pagination-list">';
          previous_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>'); 
          wp_pagenavi(); 
          next_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>');
          echo '</div>';
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас цикл рановато заканчивается.

Приведенный краткий пример ниже - полностью рабочий шаблон страницы. Добавьте HTML по вкусу.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Test Page */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args=array( 'category_name' => 'news','paged'=>$paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); 
  the_excerpt();

endwhile;


previous_posts_link(); 
wp_pagenavi(); 
next_posts_link(); 


endif;

wp_reset_postdata();    
?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: я подправил код по вашему образцу, но к сожалению проблему это не решило

Comment: я, кажется, нашел причину, я добавил 'showposts' => '2' к атрибутам, и оно мне показало все посты, со всех категорий, из ровно на 6 страниц, то есть раньше оно мне показывало только 1 категорию, но создавало страницы для всех, а как сделать так, чтобы и кол-во страниц оно создавало только для 1 категории?

Comment: я почти решил проблему, добавив параметр в wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) ); и теперь оно отображает действительное кол-во страниц, но на последней странице все равно присутствует стрелка перехода на следующую страницу, которая пустая

Comment: Что-то в настройках WP или плагина не то. У меня приведенный шаблон работает как надо, все страницы показывает.